# Switched Windows Server machines and generating date string in a batch file produces different results

Tags: windows, batch, script, batch-file

I have this line in a batch script that I use.

```
set ldt=%Date:~8,2%%Date:~3,2%%Date:~0,2%_%Time:~0,2%%Time:~3,2%%Time:~6,2%
```

It has been working fine and generating text like below since I wrote it.

```
170420_92444
```

But now on the new machine (which is still Windows Server 2008 R2) it generates something like this.

```
9/ 0We_184000
```

I can't quite figure out why this has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the locale/User-settings dependent %date% %time% variables. Use wmic instead:

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set _DT=%%A
Set ldt=%_DT:~2,6%_%_DT:~8,6%
set ldt
```

Sample output.

```
ldt=170420_121402
```